# Can I delete xxxxxxxAreaRegistration.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

If I am registering the route to an area (say it's called Admin) in the `global.asax` file rather than the area's `AdminAreaRegistration.cs` file, is there any reason why I can't delete the `AdminAreaRegistration.cs` file? Is there any other code in the framework that may call into it at some stage which might throw an exception if it is missing?

**As asked in comments, here is the code to register an Area in global.asax**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminAreaRoute",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "Payntbrush.Presentation.Demo.MVC3.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
).DataTokens.Add("Area", "Admin");

routes.MapRoute(
    "SiteAreaRoute",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { controller = "/|Home|Account" }, // Constraint's on the URL (second param above) {controller} segment
    new string[] { "Payntbrush.Presentation.Demo.MVC3.Areas.Site.Controllers" }
).DataTokens.Add("Area", "Site");
```

The key is in using the DataTokens collection, as highlighted in [this excellent post](http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/07/mvc-areas-routes-order-of-routes-matter/) by Phillip Haydon. You can add as many as you want, but make sure you put the root site area after the explicitly named areas so that `{controller}/{action}/{id}` doesn't catch all the requests before the other Map Routes can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deleted these files and haven't had any problems so far. I'm going to assume that it is OK until I run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code that you are using to register your area in the global.asax?

The reason that I ask, is I don't think that it is technically possible to get an area working  ***correctly*** without the xxxAreaRegistration.cs class implemented somewhere (even if in another project.

It might seem like it is working without it but in reality I think you might simply telling .net that your route is pointing to a sub directory.

I would expect you to get an error at some point.

Have a look at msdn [AreaRegistration Class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402905.aspx) it says

> Provides a way to register one or more areas in an ASP.NET MVC application.

while it doesn't say that its the only way, I think that might be the case.

Comment: I've added the code to achieve that above. This works fine, however what I'm trying to find out is whether there is other code within the MVC 3 framework that may try and call into the xxxAreaRegistration class at some stage. If I delete it, then there will be an null exception.

Comment: Chris, the issue here is that you will get an error if you try and access that area without having a route registered for it. So as long as you have registered it you shouldn't get any errors when accessing that area. This is the only time that .net will need or look for the arearegistration or a registered route.

Comment: I can't check now but I'm 90% the other day I deleted teh AreaRegistration file in the Area and soely relied on the "AdminAreaRoute" route in global.asax and the request was routed correctly. I'll double check next chance I get.